# error: failure reading sector 0x1007f0 from 'hd0'

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, hard-drive

Some months ago I installed ubuntu 16.04 in a Hard Disk (WD Elements 1TB 2.5" USB 3.0). In order to run the computer from HD, I installed GNU Gurb (version 2.02^beta2-36ubuntu3.8). Untill yesterday it work's perfectly, but today I don't know why it failed. I have run the computer with F9, chenged boot to ubuntu and then my computer returned this:

```
      error: failure reading sector 0x1007f0 from 'hd0'.

      error: failure reading sector 0x100780 from 'hd0'.

      error: failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0'.

      error: failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0'.

      error: failure reading sector 0xfc from 'hd2'.

      error: failure reading sector 0xe0 from 'hd2'.

      error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd2'.

      error: failure reading sector 0x1007f0 from 'hd0'.

      error: failure reading sector 0x100780 from 'hd0'.

      error: failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0'.

      error: failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0'.
```

Then all of this disappears and appears GNU GRUB starting:

```
                   GNU GRUB version 2.02^beta2-36ubuntu3.8
  Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
  lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
  device or file completions.

  grub> _
```

Does somebody know how to solve this problem? I have important projects saved in my Hard Disk !!

Thank's !

Comment: Looks like the bootloader broke. Boot from a live usb/cd and verify the disk is not damaged, if not, reinstall grub.

Comment: Okey, thank's! I tried it and it works, so I think that my disk is damaged...

Comment: I see both hd2 and hd0... A bit scary that both disks are showing errors. While you are booted from Live USB/CD, run e2fsck to see if the errors persist. Secondly, you show your WD is USB30 is it connected to USB3 when the errors occur?  If so, what if connected to USB2?  Same ??

Comment: USB cables/ports/hub (built-into the computer) could be loose or failing... If you've got really important files they should always have at least one backup somewhere (separate drive, USB, some cloud, etc)

Comment: @Williem K I don't know how to run e2fsck... And yes, I've the same problem connecting WD to USB2. Thank's!

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, that's my fault.... I will do it next time! Thank's!!

Comment: You must boot the Live USB/CD because the disks can only be checked if they are not mounted. Determine the type of file system the disk is and run e2fsck if its ext2/ext3/ext4. Otherwise use fsck.
Command (for example):  (e2)fsck  /dev/hd0